# What are pathname conventions for ZwCreateFile/ZwOpenFile?

Tags: driver, windows-kernel

I noticed that `ZwOpenFile` doesn't tolerate ".." and "." in the pathname (and yet ZwQueryDirectoryFile returns these during enumeration).

1. Is there any way to open parent directory using a handle to a child dir? (assuming you don't know fully qualified path)
2. Where can I read on pathname conventions these functions use?

Comment: The notion of relative path names, and a default directory for a drive, only exists in the winapi layer.  The native OS requires full path names.

Comment: all path transformations ("/" to "\", ".." "." etc is done when it converted from win32 form to nt in *RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U* . nt layer never transform path or use special symbols like "." or "..". however nt can use full or relative paths in `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`. file path we always can got via `ZwQueryObject` with `ObjectNameInformation` (in both user and kernel mode) or via `ObQueryNameString`.

Comment: for open open parent directory need first get full path of child and then or in kernel mode use [`IoCreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548418(v=vs.85).aspx) with `IO_OPEN_TARGET_DIRECTORY` in Options flags. or, in user mode, yourself remove last path component. can use `RtlGetLengthWithoutLastFullDosOrNtPathElement` for this too. unfortunately `IO_OPEN_TARGET_DIRECTORY` not support relative file open (with `RootDirectory` and empty `ObjectName` in `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`) - as result and need query full path first.

Comment: also read [The Definitive Guide on Win32 to NT Path Conversion](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-on-win32-to-nt.html)

Comment: @HansPassant Then why `ZwQueryDirectoryFile(..., FileBothDirectoryInformation, ...)` returns "." and ".." along with other directory items? (unless directory being enumerated is a root one some drive)

Comment: @RbMm Is there any reliable way to get a full path for given handle (that was opened using ZwCreate/etc)?

Comment: @C.M. - `any reliable way to get a full path for given handle` - of course yes. strange question. `ZwQueryObject` with `ObjectNameInformation` (in both user and kernel mode) or `ObQueryNameString`.  both this return full path (device name + filesystem path). the `FileNameInformation` for `ZwQueryInformationFile` return only filesystem path, without device name